# Paging in Joomla

Tags: joomla, pagination, paging

I am new to joomla. I am trying to create a webpage which shows data from my database (I am using php with Sourcerer plugin). Data contains profile of users with image. Now i want to display 5 user profile per page (using pagination). It's just one menu (page) in which I want pagination. 
I've gone through many links for this but could not find exact solution.
Plz help me.

Thanks

Comment: Pagination is used all over the core, have you tried looking at examples from there?  For example look at any category list layout and how it uses the core pagination.

Answer (score 0):

Above the constructor and below the class definition put this code

```
class ComUserModel extends JModel
{

    var $_pagination = null;

    function __construct() 
    {
```

In the constructor of the model your are using, let's assume that it's user model

```
function __construct() 
{
    $this->_app =& JFactory::getApplication();
    parent::__construct();

    // Get pagination request variables
    $limit = $this->_app->getUserStateFromRequest(OPTIOIN_NAME.'.user.limit', 'limit', $this->_app->getCfg('list_limit'), 'int');
    $limitstart = $this->_app->getUserStateFromRequest(OPTIOIN_NAME.'.user.limitstart', 'limitstart', 0, 'int');

    // In case limit has been changed, adjust it
    $limitstart = ($limit != 0 ? (floor($limitstart / $limit) * $limit) : 0);

    // Set States
    $this->setState(OPTIOIN_NAME.'.user.limit', $limit);
    $this->setState(OPTIOIN_NAME.'.user.limitstart', $limitstart);
}
```

Add below function to the model

```
function pagination()
{
    if($this->_pagination == NULL)
        $this->_pagination = new JPagination(20, $this->getState(OPTIOIN_NAME.'.user.limitstart'), $this->getState(OPTIOIN_NAME.'.user.limit'));
    return $this->_pagination;
}
```

When you retrive data,

```
function getUsers()
{
    // Set the Limits and Filters
    $limit = $this->getState(OPTIOIN_NAME.'.user.limit');
    $limitstart = $this->getState(OPTIOIN_NAME.'.user.limitstart');

    //get db             
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();
    $count_query = 'count(*)';
    $select_query = '*';
    $from_query = $db->nameQuote(TABLE_PREFIX.'user_table');               


    //build the query
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query->select($select_query);
    $query->from($from_query); 
    $query->order($db->nameQuote('id').' desc');       
    $db->setQuery($query);               


    //build count query
    $cquery = $db->getQuery(true);
    $cquery->select($count_query);
    $cquery->from($from_query); 
    $cquery->order($db->nameQuote('id').' desc');       
    $db->setQuery($cquery);               
    $total = $db->loadResult();


    if ($db->getErrorNum())
    {
        $this->_app->enqueueMessage($db->stderr(), 'error');
        return false;
    }        
    //setup the pagination
    $this->_pagination  = new JPagination($total, $limitstart, $limit);     

    //get the data within limits
    $data       = $this->_getList($query, $limitstart, $limit);        

    if ($db->getErrorNum())
    {
        $this->_app->enqueueMessage($db->stderr(), 'error');
        return false;
    }

    return $data; 
}
```

In the controller

```
function getalluser()
{   

    $model      = $this->getModel('user');        
    $data       = $model->getUsers();  
    $pagination = $model->pagination();

    $view = $this->getView('userlist', 'html');
    $view->assignRef('data',$data);
    $view->assignRef('pagination', $pagination);        
    $view->display();
}
```

In the view put the code where you want the pagination

```
<?php echo $this->pagination->getListFooter(); ?>
```

If you have any issues let me know